# Error "The value you selected is not a valid choice." in drop down list

Tags: 8, nodes

I want to list node titles in drop-down list programmatically.
I have done below code in form_alter hook.

```
function product_custom_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == 'node_inventory_form') {
  $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','product')->execute();
  $nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
  $product_title = array();
  $product_title['_none'] = " - None -";
  foreach ($nodes as $node_content) {
     $title = $node_content->getTitle();
     $product_title[$title] = $title;
  }
  $form['product_name']['widget']['#options'] = $product_title;
 }
}
```

It showing the title list proper but i'm getting this error **"Error message The value you selected is not a valid choice."** while saving the node.

Comment: The submitted option(s) are validated against the known valid options for the field - if the values you're injecting differ form those valid options, that's why you see the message

Comment: Options value attaching dynamically and it's valid. How to differ if it's valid option or not?